# QListWidget performance with many custom items

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I have a list with about 2500 custom items. I set them with:

```
 const std::vector<const Items::AbstractItem *> results = _engine.request(text);
    if (!results.empty())
    {
        for (auto i : results){
            QListWidgetItem *lwi = new QListWidgetItem;
            _results->addItem(lwi);
            ListItemWidget *w = new ListItemWidget;
            w->setName(i->name());
            w->setTooltip(i->path());
            _results->setItemWidget(lwi, w);
        }
        _results->setFixedHeight(std::min(5,_results->count()) * 48); // TODO
        _results->show();
    }
```

This takes about 5 seconds on an i5-4590. Hiding the widget is twice as fast. Is this normal or do I have look for errors?

Comment: As always when dealing with performance running a profiler is what you should start with because it is better than speculations and trials. The only idea I get now about your problem is that you could perhaps pre-allocate items, but I don't really think memory allocation could be the issue here. Perhaps painting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fully expected behavior for controls like `Lists` or `Trees` that are not based on any `data model`. And I believe that the `data model` was invented mainly to fix this issue.

In your situation you have a `ListWidget` control that stores its data on its own. You need to pass all 2500 items before your app can go on, and you need to do this even if your list shows only 10 items at a time. Even if you just run and close your app, the user won't see all the items but you still need to pass them to your `ListWidget`. Some GUI frameworks use internal allocation of items and in such case they can optimize things a bit, you could do the same if you allocated your `Items` in chunks but it's still not a good solution.

Now let's say you introduce some object that could be **asked** about item properties. The `Control` will **ask about** some item and your object will respond with the contents. Your object don't even need to know about all your items, it will just learn when needed.
You `Control` can ask about few first items and stop when it realize it can fill up its entire height. This way you can avoid work that is not needed for now. The `Control` can also ask about the item count, so it can set-up its vertical slider.

It needs to be said that the `model` will not solve your problem automatically, it's just a programming paradigm that allows you to do it better.

So the solution for you would be to replace your QListWidget with a QListView and implement you own data model inheriting `QAbstractListModel`. You could pass the `results` to the model and it will pass the items data when needed.

Comment: Is lazy population implemented by default or do I have to force/enable it?

Comment: In `QListView` you don't enable/disable it, it's just a result of a data model approach, but you need to implement your model correctly, so it loads the data only when needed.

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas:

- Try assigning proper parents to your QWidgets, thats way the layout doesn't have to do this 
  mapping for you. This should help performance.
- Call setUpdatesEnable(false) before starting the insert, and to true after it's done

As for hiding the widget while adding large amounts of items, this will help to alleviate extraneous update calls. The second suggestion above should mitigate that.

Comment: setUpdatesEnable(false) does not work. At least in 5.3. The first did not make any noticeable difference.

Answer (score 1):

If your `QListWidgetItem`'s always has fixed size, call `setUniformItemSizes` on your `QListWidget`, pass true.